# Magento Undefined index: httponly error after XAMPP upgrade

Tags: magento, xampp

I recently upgraded my version of XAMPP (on OS X) and all my magento sites running locally are getting this error:

Notice: Undefined index: httponly  in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysite/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php on line 94

Has anyone come across this issue before or have any idea what could be causing it? I've found very little on the web relating to it so far.

Comment: I am having the same issue while i was coding a handler that actually creates customer and try to create a logged in session for the same user. I believe this is something related with the Mage session. Love to hear from any who has the solution to this issue.

Answer (score 2):

```
Comment the following section of the code in
 **htdocs/mysite/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php**

/*if (!$cookieParams['httponly']) {
    unset($cookieParams['httponly']);
    if (!$cookieParams['secure']) {
        unset($cookieParams['secure']);
        if (!$cookieParams['domain']) {
            unset($cookieParams['domain']);
        }
    }
}

if (isset($cookieParams['domain'])) {
    $cookieParams['domain'] = $cookie->getDomain();
}*/
```

Comment: Modifying Magento core files is bad practice. You should not do this. Secondly, commenting something out does not solve the problem, you are just ignoring it.